# Adding a library to the @INC array in perl

Tags: perl

I am running a script which requires the Curl.pm lib in order to work. I used YUM to install the library and now I am trying to have my script use it, but I keep getting the error

`Can't locate WWW/Curl.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.6/x86_...`

When I type the following in the command line:

rpm -ql curl

I get:

```
/usr/bin/curl
/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.3
/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.3.0.0
/usr/share/doc/curl-7.13.1
/usr/share/doc/curl-7.13.1/BUGS
/usr/share/doc/curl-7.13.1/CHANGES
/usr/share/doc/curl-7.13.1/COPYING
/usr/share/doc/curl-7.13.1/FAQ
 ...
/usr/share/man/man1/curl.1.gz
/usr/bin/curl
/usr/lib/libcurl.so.3
/usr/lib/libcurl.so.3.0.0
/usr/share/doc/curl-7.13.1
/usr/share/doc/curl-7.13.1/BUGS
/usr/share/doc/curl-7.13.1/CHANGES
... etc.
```

Which one of the paths above needs to be included in my @INC directory? I had thought that the code below would solve the problem when placed at the top of my script, but I am still getting the same error @INC error.

```
BEGIN {
  unshift(@INC, '/usr/lib/libcurl.so.3');
  use WWW::Curl;
}
```

When I type

```
cpan> i /WWW::curl/
```

I get the following list below.  I'm still stumped. I want to use WWW::curl and I don't know which of the paths below (or above) to add to @INC ! It looks like it's already installed. What do I do from here?

```
cpan> i /WWW::curl/
CPAN: Storable loaded ok
Going to read /root/.cpan/Metadata 
Database was generated on Mon, 30 Nov 2009 02:55:47 GMT
Module          WWW::Curl       (S/SZ/SZBALINT/WWW-Curl-4.09.tar.gz)
Module          WWW::Curl::Easy (S/SZ/SZBALINT/WWW-Curl-4.09.tar.gz)
Module          WWW::Curl::Form (S/SZ/SZBALINT/WWW-Curl-4.09.tar.gz)
Module          WWW::Curl::Multi (S/SZ/SZBALINT/WWW-Curl-4.09.tar.gz)  
Module          WWW::Curl::Share (S/SZ/SZBALINT/WWW-Curl-4.09.tar.gz)
Module          WWW::Curl::Simple (A/AN/ANDREMAR/WWW-Curl-Simple-0.05.tar.gz)
Module          WWW::Curl::Simple::Request (A/AN/ANDREMAR/WWW-Curl-Simple-0.05.tar.gz)
7 items found
```

Comment: ...Or if his advice did not work, post your progress as an edit of your question, so you can get further advice. Just leaving the question hanging is impolite.

Comment: `WWW::Curl` and `WWW::curl` are different. So are `i /WWW::Curl/` and `install WWW::Curl`

Comment: I have not yet found a solution to my problem and do not want to make a question as 'answered' until my problem is solved. I tried almost all the suggestions given to me in both posts ... when someone comes in the future to read this post looking for a solution, I want to be sure that they read what actually solved my problem.
BTW, it takes time to try out these suggestions .... I am trying to solve the problem as quickly as I can and when I do I promise to return and 'answer' the question.

Comment: *They’re not evil creatures, Help Vampires. They act only on their blind instinct to feed, driven by base urges like most living things. Often even they themselves are not aware of their Help Vampire status, so leave your stakes at home.* http://slash7.com/articles/2006/12/22/vampires

Comment: You have received two suggestions: First one asked you to run "install WWW::Curl" inside the CPAN shell and the second suggested that you install the rpm. Which one did not work? Did you get any errors? If you did, post them here and someone here will suggest what to do.

Comment: @Gurunandan Just to be sure, I do think using `yum` is the right way to go if the package already exists. Use `cpan` only if an OS specific package does not exist.

Comment: when I run "install WWW::Curl" from the CPAN shell, I get the following:

8 tests skipped.
Failed 1/19 test scripts, 94.74% okay. 1/156 subtests failed, 99.36% okay.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
Running make install
  "make test had returned bad status, won't install without force"

When I run my script, I get the same error. When I try to push '/lib' into the path before 'using' the WWW::Curl lib, I also get the same error. 
I pushed the '/lib' in my @INC array because it looked like it was put there
"cp lib/WWW/Curl/Share.pm blib/lib/WWW/Curl/Share.pm"

Comment: @Miriam Raphael Roberts: Again, use **OS specific packages if they are available**. Have you even tried `yum install perl-WWW-Curl`? What test script failed during `cpan WWW::Curl`?

Comment: When I run "yum install perl-WWW-Curl" I get the following:
No Match for argument: perl-WWW-Curl
Nothing to do
This is not my server which is why  I knew I was going to have problems installing using special libraries...I got my original program to work which allows me to avoid using these special perl libraries. The post is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821270/how-to-configure-server-to-enable-curl
I no longer need to install these libraries.

Answer (score 8):

You installed `curl` which is not the same thing as `WWW::Curl`.

You need to install the Perl module [`WWW::Curl`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Curl). ***You should first search your OS specific package repositories for the module.*** If you cannot find it there, use [`cpanm`](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus) to install it:

```
$ cpanm WWW::Curl
```

See also [`perldoc perlmodinstall`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodinstall.html).

Answer (score 8):

You have installed the curl library. To install the WWW::Curl module do this:

```
yum install perl-WWW-Curl
```

Answer (score 2):

I am going to ignore that chaos that I see and simply answer the question:

1. You don't add libraries to `@INC`, you add directories. The directories you add contain Perl modules, i.e. `*.pm` files.
2. To do that, you simply use `use lib`. If the directory you want to add is `/foo/bar`:

```
use lib qw| /foo/bar |;
```

Comment: @Manni It is hard to ignore the chaos, primarily because if the OP were to install `WWW::Curl` via either the OS specific package manager or `cpan`, adding paths to `@INC` would not be necessary. +1.

Comment: Sinan: I took me two hours to get myself in the right state of mind to ingore the chaos. Thanks for the upvote.